# Google Map React component loses data when placed into divs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-maps-react

I have a working GoogleMapReact component that takes latitude and longitude, and places markers on the map.  The problem I face is I need to style the Marker component and when I place it into DIV  or any other html element, all markes lose their coordinates and are just in vertical row on the map.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import getCenter from "geolib/es/getCenter";
import Marker from "../components/Marker";

function MapMe1({ searchResults }) {
  

  //transform the search results object into {latitude,longitude} format
  const coordinates = searchResults.map((result) => ({
    longitude: result.long,
    latitude: result.lat,
  }));

  const center = getCenter(coordinates);

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "600px",
    height: "max-height: 75%",

    center: { lat: center.latitude, lng: center.longitude },

    zoom: 11,
  });

  return (
    <GoogleMapReact
      //mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}

      bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.google_maps_key }}
      {...viewport}
      onViewportChange={(nextViewport) => setViewport(nextViewport)}
    >
      {searchResults.map((result) => (
      // It works, but if I wrap this in <div> lat and lng no longer available...
        <Marker
          lat={result.lat}
          lng={result.long}
          offsetLeft={-20}
          offsetTop={-10}
          titles={result.title}
        />
      ))}
    </GoogleMapReact>
  );
}

export default MapMe1;
```

I want to style the marker to show a tooltip but for some reason is the Marker component loses all  data. Why is this happening?

Comment: The docs have a good example of this using StyledComponents: https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/tree/90f032b7e426bb5da4a9502b996e80b2b6993528/example

Comment: It looks like <Marker> is a component created by you. Can't you just style the component by adding styles to the div in the "../components/Marker" file? Why do you need to wrap this component with another div?

Comment: Yes, if I style this inside Marker component, it works. But this is quite work intensive if you have many components. It would be easier to do all styling in one place. And for some reason it cannot be done from top-level component..